# How to set auto_delete=False for all new queues in Celery?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, celery-task

How can one set the default value of auto_delete to False for all new created queues by Celery using  AMQP? I use the default settings. So the default "celery" exchange is auto_delete = False. Adding a task like this

```
result = client.send_task('abc')
```

results in a queue with auto_delete = True.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a queue, exchange or binding is a bit like ‘Single Assignment’ in Erlang, 
if you declared it once with auto_delete=False then you cannot later declare 
it to be auto_delete=True.  To change the definition you must delete it first.

Notice also that Exchange.auto_delete is deprecated as it does not work very well, 
and it’s **not supported by librabbitmq**.

Source: [Celery User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/3dKJHA5Y2Ig)

Comment: The question was asking how to change the default setting for celery, not about how to change an existing exchange.